# New User deployment failure

Tags: ruby, deployment

I started going through the Odin project's curriculum, started using Ubuntu, and am going through [Installfests guide on deploying a Rails App.](http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/deploy_a_rails_app) I'm having trouble at step 2.5.

Here is the result I get:

```
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 117, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (103/103), done.
Writing objects: 100% (117/117), 25.89 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 117 (delta 8), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.3.4
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.13.7
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.13.7) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.14.6). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
remote:        Installing rake 12.0.0
remote:        Installing i18n 0.8.1
remote:        Installing concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
remote:        Installing minitest 5.10.1
remote:        Installing thread_safe 0.3.6
remote:        Installing builder 3.2.3
remote:        Installing erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Installing mini_portile2 2.1.0
remote:        Installing nio4r 2.0.0 with native extensions
remote:        Installing rack 2.0.1
remote:        Installing websocket-extensions 0.1.2
remote:        Installing arel 7.1.4
remote:        Installing mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
remote:        Installing coffee-script-source 1.12.2
remote:        Installing execjs 2.7.0
remote:        Installing thor 0.19.4
remote:        Installing method_source 0.8.2
remote:        Installing multi_json 1.12.1
remote:        Installing pg 0.20.0 with native extensions
remote:        Installing puma 3.8.2 with native extensions
remote:        Using bundler 1.13.7
remote:        Installing sass 3.4.23
remote:        Installing tilt 2.0.7
remote:        Installing turbolinks-source 5.0.0
remote:        Installing tzinfo 1.2.3
remote:        Installing nokogiri 1.7.1 with native extensions
remote:        Installing rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Installing sprockets 3.7.1
remote:        Installing websocket-driver 0.6.5 with native extensions
remote:        Installing mime-types 3.1
remote:        Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Installing uglifier 3.2.0
remote:        Installing turbolinks 5.0.1
remote:        Installing activesupport 5.0.2
remote:        Installing mail 2.6.4
remote:        Installing globalid 0.4.0
remote:        Installing activemodel 5.0.2
remote:        Installing jbuilder 2.6.3
remote:        Installing activejob 5.0.2
remote:        Installing activerecord 5.0.2
remote:        Installing rails-dom-testing 2.0.2
remote:        Installing loofah 2.0.3
remote:        Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Installing actionview 5.0.2
remote:        Installing actionpack 5.0.2
remote:        Installing actioncable 5.0.2
remote:        Installing actionmailer 5.0.2
remote:        Installing railties 5.0.2
remote:        Installing sprockets-rails 3.2.0
remote:        Installing rails 5.0.2
remote:        Installing coffee-rails 4.2.1
remote:        Installing sass-rails 5.0.6
remote:        Installing jquery-rails 4.3.1
remote:        Bundle complete! 16 Gemfile dependencies, 53 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
remote:        Bundle completed (26.35s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: -----> Installing node-v6.10.0-linux-x64
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        NoMethodError: undefined method `roots' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x007fc37aff5b28>
remote:        /tmp/build_e6fc23c1f302b4f1aa2bdeafdf93c2f5/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_e6fc23c1f302b4f1aa2bdeafdf93c2f5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:389:in `instance_exec'
remote:        /tmp/build_e6fc23c1f302b4f1aa2bdeafdf93c2f5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:389:in `eval_block'
remote:        /tmp/build_e6fc23c1f302b4f1aa2bdeafdf93c2f5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:371:in `draw'
remote:        /tmp/build_e6fc23c1f302b4f1aa2bdeafdf93c2f5/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_e6fc23c1f302b4f1aa2bdeafdf93c2f5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_e6fc23c1f302b4f1aa2bdeafdf93c2f5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_e6fc23c1f302b4f1aa2bdeafdf93c2f5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_e6fc23c1f302b4f1aa2bdeafdf93c2f5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_e6fc23c1f302b4f1aa2bdeafdf93c2f5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_e6fc23c1f302b4f1aa2bdeafdf93c2f5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_e6fc23c1f302b4f1aa2bdeafdf93c2f5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_e6fc23c1f302b4f1aa2bdeafdf93c2f5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
remote:        /tmp/build_e6fc23c1f302b4f1aa2bdeafdf93c2f5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
remote:        /tmp/build_e6fc23c1f302b4f1aa2bdeafdf93c2f5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:77:in `execute'
remote:        /tmp/build_e6fc23c1f302b4f1aa2bdeafdf93c2f5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
remote:        /tmp/build_e6fc23c1f302b4f1aa2bdeafdf93c2f5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
remote:        /tmp/build_e6fc23c1f302b4f1aa2bdeafdf93c2f5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:119:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
remote:        /tmp/build_e6fc23c1f302b4f1aa2bdeafdf93c2f5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
remote:        /tmp/build_e6fc23c1f302b4f1aa2bdeafdf93c2f5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
remote:        /tmp/build_e6fc23c1f302b4f1aa2bdeafdf93c2f5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_e6fc23c1f302b4f1aa2bdeafdf93c2f5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_e6fc23c1f302b4f1aa2bdeafdf93c2f5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
remote:        /tmp/build_e6fc23c1f302b4f1aa2bdeafdf93c2f5/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_e6fc23c1f302b4f1aa2bdeafdf93c2f5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_e6fc23c1f302b4f1aa2bdeafdf93c2f5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
remote:        /tmp/build_e6fc23c1f302b4f1aa2bdeafdf93c2f5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:448:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
remote:        /tmp/build_e6fc23c1f302b4f1aa2bdeafdf93c2f5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_e6fc23c1f302b4f1aa2bdeafdf93c2f5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => environment
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to evening-harbor-57945.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/evening-harbor-57945.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/evening-harbor-57945.git'
```

I tried different things such as editing my gem file replacing:

```
gem 'sqlite3'
```

with:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

I also tried updating the gemfile as stated in the feedback from my `git push heroku master` by entering:

```
gem install bundler
```

but it yields the same results.

Comment: I'd recommend reading "[How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)" in its entirety. We don't care what your experience is, we only want well researched and well asked questions. "[ask]" and "[mcve]" are important, as is "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)". Remove everything from the question that doesn't directly explain the problem, especially apologizing. Keep it concise and clear. Your question is the opening to a new entry in an encyclopedia, so write that way.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. Gerry got me turned back in the right direction, and I'll also take better care with my phrasing in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your log and you will find the error:

```
remote:        NoMethodError: undefined method `roots' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x007fc37aff5b28>
remote:        /tmp/build_e6fc23c1f302b4f1aa2bdeafdf93c2f5/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

If you read carefully, you will find file and line number where the error was generated: `config/routes.rb:2`.

From that i assume that you used `roots` instead of `root` in step **2.3**, so open `config/routes.rb` and check that you have this:

```
root 'drinks#index'
```

That should fix your problem.